# Spark Streaming fails due to "exceeding memory limits"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd, google-cloud-dataproc

I  am running Spark (1.6.1) Streaming on YARN, with 8 nodes.
Reading files from hdfs and writes to ES.

transformations :-

1. mapToPair
2. reduceByKey
3. mapToPair

Output operation:-

1. foreachRDD

While process is running the storage in Receiver node is piling up continuously.
I tried to reduce the SparkStreamingContext-remember to 60secs.

```
Total Uptime: 3.6 h
Scheduling Mode: FIFO 
Completed Jobs: 12798
Completed Stages: 20592
```

Error in yarn log:

```
16/06/14 14:41:08 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 40.1 GB of 40 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/06/14 14:41:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on spark-metrics-0-w-7.c.orion-0010.internal: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 40.1 GB of 40 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/06/14 14:41:08 WARN org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 70, spark-metrics-0-w-7.c.orion-0010.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 40.1 GB of 40 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
16/06/14 14:41:08 WARN org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from spark-metrics-0-w-7.c.orion-0010.internal/10.240.1.110:56101
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/14 14:41:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from spark-metrics-0-w-7.c.orion-0010.internal/10.240.1.110:56101 is closed
16/06/14 14:41:08 WARN org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster: Failed to remove RDD 63963 - Connection reset by peer
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/14 14:41:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost an executor 1 (already removed): Pending loss reason.
16/06/14 14:41:08 ERROR org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1465915267000 ms.0
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/14 14:41:10 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/06/14 14:41:10 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/06/14 14:41:10 INFO akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
Job output is complete
```

Comment: Did you read the error message well ? I would start there. This is not salvageable with current details.

Comment: @eliasah , updated with full error-log, I couldnt understand more from the logs.

Comment: @remisharoon - I think eliash was referring to this note in the error log line: Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead. When you say you are writing to ES - is that a full remote ES cluster or in-process ES? Can you verify that writes are being applied and not being buffered in the client (or limit the amount of client buffering)?

Comment: @AngusDavis , writes are happening to ES, job runs fine for sometime, some times 3 hrs, sometimes 30mins, and then throws this error and fails. about increasing memory, I tried that option still it fails, now the memory is 40G, beyond that, even if it helps wont allow my budget

Comment: Where does your ES cluster run? Is it on other GCE VMs in the same GCE zone as your Dataproc cluster? Based on your previous screenshot it looks like your blocks are all going to a single executor; are you always reading only from a single HDFS file? You might want to try repartitioning your DStream to better utilize multiple executors, like `myDStream = myDStream.repartition(8)` or however many executors you have, as explained in the [performance tuning](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#level-of-parallelism-in-data-receiving)